# Difference between Add and AddRange in arrayList c#

Tags: c#

Can anyone tell when to use `Add()` and `AddRange()` of `ArrayList`?

Comment: `Add` adds a singular value, e.g. `Add(1)` while `AddRange` adds a `IEnumerable<T>` values, e.g. `AddRange(new int[] {1, 2, 3})`

Comment: A simple search will take you to lots of good articles including MSDN Docs. http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2007/09/21/Add-vs.-AddRange.aspx

Comment: Why don't you just read their documentations? By the way, it is 2015. Don't use `ArrayList` anymore (if you do). It belongs old days when C# doesn't have Generics. Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.arraylist(v=vs.110).aspx just look in the doc

Comment: You should have found answer from google.

Comment: Did you read the methosds' documentation?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to add a large number of values at one time, use [AddRange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.addrange%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
If you are only adding a single value or adding values infrequently, use [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 12):

**Difference Between Add and AddRange**

`Add`: It is used to add the item into the list one by one.

`AddRange`: It is used to add the bulk of list item into the another list.

```
List<string>list1=new List<string>();//using Add
List<string>list2=new List<string>();//using AddRange
list1.Add("Malathi");
list1.Add("Sandhiya");
list1.Add("Ramya");
list1.Add("Mithra");
list1.Add("Dharshini");

list2.AddRange(list1);
```

The output of `list1` contains:

- Malathi,
  Sandhiya,
  Ramya,
  Mithra,
  Dharshini

The output of `list2` contains:

- Malathi,
  Sandhiya,
  Ramya,
  Mithra,
  Dharshini

Answer (score 1):

C# List class represents a collection of a type in C#. **List.Add(), List.AddRange(), List.Insert(), and List.InsertRange()** methods are used to add and insert items to a List.

***AddRange*** - AddRange adds an entire collection of elements. It can replace tedious foreach-loops that repeatedly call Add on List.

```
public virtual void AddRange (System.Collections.ICollection c);
```

***Add*** - Add method adds an object to the end of the List.

```
public virtual int Add (object value);
```

Example: Now set an array of elements to be added to the list.

```
// array of 4 elements
int[] arr = new int[4];
arr[0] = 500;
arr[1] = 600;
arr[2] = 700;
arr[3] = 800;
```

Use the AddRange() method add the entire collection of elements in the list −

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.AddRange(arr);
```

But if you want to use List.Add() method,

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(100);
list.Add(200);
list.Add(300);
list.Add(400);
```

For details, you can check [Insert an Item into a C# List](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/insert-item-into-a-C-Sharp-list/)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to add single variable in List, then Add() is used.
But if you want to add List or multiple variable in List, then AddRange() can be used

```
var t = (from t1 intable1
         join t2 in table2 on t1.t1id equals t2.t2id
         select new ABCViewModel
         {
             FirstName = t1.firstname,
             LastName = t1.Lastname
         })
        .where(t2.age>35)
        .ToList();
var s = (from t1 intable1
         join t2 in table2 on t1.t1id equals t2.t2id
         select new ABCViewModel
         {
             FirstName = t1.firstname,
             LastName = t1.Lastname
         })
        .where(t2.age < 35)
        .ToList();
t.AddRange(s);
return t;
```

It will add result of List s to List t along with result of List t.

Answer (score 0):

Difference b/w `Add()` and `AddRange()` methods is very straight forward

`Add()` is used to add an element in the list.

`AddRange()` is used to add a range of elements(multiple elements) at once in the list.

Note: Multiple elements can be another entire `Array`, `HashTable`, `SortedList`, `ArrayList`, `BitArray`, `Queue`, and `Stack`.

Answer (score -3):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{

class Program
    {

  static void Main(string[] args)
        {

  //create the first arraylist

            ArrayList arraylist1 = new ArrayList();

            arraylist1.Add(5);

            arraylist1.Add(7);

            //create the second arraylist

            ArrayList arraylist2 = new ArrayList();

            arraylist2.Add("Five");//add the single value at time to the arraylist

            arraylist2.Add("Seven");//add the single value at time to the arraylist

            //perform AddRange method

            arraylist1.AddRange(arraylist2);//adding the arraylist as bulk in another arraylist

            // Display the values.

            foreach (object i in arraylist1)//iterating the arraylist1 value to object
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```